# Failing RSpec test with strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

I am migrating my Rails 4 app (still using protected attributes gem) to Rails 5.1.4. In the course of this action, I need to rewrite a lot of code to replace protected attributes with strong parameters.

I am currently stuck on one specific controller where my RSpec tests fail, and I don't know how to implement the controller and test logic such that things are correct and tests pass.

The app has an admin backend where users can add (and thus upload) photos to an album. The respective Admin::PhotosController handles the photos of an album.

Here's the relevant exerpt from my app:

```
def create
  # @organizer_account is set by an before_filter
  @album = @organizer_account.albums.find_by_id(params[:album_id])

  @photo = @album.photos.new(photo_params)
  @photo.organizer_account_id = @organizer_account.id

  authorize! :create, @photo

  respond_to do |format|
    if @photo.save

      format.html {
        render :json => [@photo.to_jq_file].to_json, :content_type => 'text/html', :layout => false
      }
      format.json { 
        files = [ @photo.to_jq_file ]
        render :json => {:files => [@photo.to_jq_file] }, :status => :created, :location => admin_album_photo_path(@album, @photo) 
      }

    else
      format.html { 
        render action: "new" 
      }
      format.json { 
        render json: @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity 
      }
    end
  end
end
```

I have defined the following strong parameters:

```
private

  def photo_params
    params.require(:photo).permit(:id, :album_id, :organizer_account_id, :file)
  end
```

The failing RSpec test is as follows:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Admin::PhotosController, :type => :controller do
  render_views  

  describe "post 'create'" do
    describe "with valid parameters" do

      before(:each) do        
        @organizer_account = FactoryBot.create(:organizer_account)        
        @user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
        @user.organizer_account_id = @organizer_account.id
        @user.add_role :admin, @organizer_account
        @user.save
        sign_in @user

        @album = @organizer_account.albums.create(:title => "Album 1")
        @photo_attrs = FactoryBot.attributes_for(:photo)

        request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] = new_admin_album_path        
        controller.request.host = @organizer_account.subdomain + ".lvh.me"
      end          

      it "should create a new photo record", :focus => true do        
        lambda {
          post :create, params: {:photo => @photo_attrs, :album_id => @album.id }
        }.should change(@organizer_account.albums.find_by_id(@album.id).photos, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I strongly assume that the issue is in parameters are a) passed

```
post :create, params: {:photo => @photo_attrs, :album_id => @album.id }
```

and then processed

```
@photo = @album.photos.new(photo_params)
```

While the params hash passed by the test has all the required entries

```
params: {"photo"=><ActionController::Parameters {"file"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000010dd7560 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/PATRIC~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20180520-11424-avge07.gif>, @original_filename="image6.gif", @content_type="image/gif", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo[file][]\"; filename=\"image6.gif\"\r\nContent-Type: image/gif\r\nContent-Length: 46844\r\n">]} permitted: false>, "album_id"=>"1561", "controller"=>"admin/photos", "action"=>"create"}
```

the photo_params is empty:

```
photo_params: {}
```

**Update #1: Definition of factory for photo**

```
FactoryBot.define do

  factory :photo, :class => Photo do
    file Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(Rails.root + 'spec/fixtures/photos/apfelkuchen.jpg', "image/jpg")
  end  

end
```

**Update #2: Photo model with file attachment and image processing config**

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'rmagick'  
  include Magick

  belongs_to :album  
  belongs_to :organizer_account

  before_destroy { |photo| photo.file.destroy }

  validates :album_id, :presence => true
  validates :organizer_account_id, :presence => true

  has_attached_file :file,
```

*# The following tyles and convert options lead to breaking RSpec tests. If commented, RSpec tests pass.*

```
                    :styles => {
                      :mini => "50x50#", 
                      :thumb => "160x160#", 
                      :large => "1200x1200>"
                    },
                    :convert_options => {
                      :mini => "-quality 75 -strip",
                      :thumb => "-quality 75 -strip"
                    }

  validates :file, :presence => true
end
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint somewhere in the controller with `byebug` or `binding.pry` and checked what the value of `params` is?

Comment: Not with byebug, but just plain console outputs. I get the output as in the post (se the last few lines). What puzzles me is that the file param is not permitted: (permitted: false) although I have added it to the list of permitted parameters.

Comment: @PatrickFrey the `album_id` is a require param for a photo creation, try to merge the album with `@photo_attrs` : `post :create, params: {:photo => @photo_attrs.merge( :album_id => @album.id) }`

Comment: @sovalina Thanks for the hint. However, still doesn't work. The file entry in the params hash simply does not get permitted. Any idea what to change here?

Comment: @PatrickFrey how did you define your photo factory ?

Comment: @sovalina added factory definition of photo to the post (see update at the end).

Comment: @sovalina OK I experimented with the factory a little bit. I ended up in some validation errors raised by Paperclip (Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError). Following up on this, I got to know that Paperclip there are some issues with style validations which only occur during testing. I have updated the post again.

Comment: I am having the same issue! The strong params are not recognizing my file param, Did you solve it?